# Html Agility Pack Xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

How can I use this xPath with Html Agility Pack?

xPath:

```
//div[@class='test']/(text())[last()]
```

I've tried this code:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='test']/(text())[last()]"))
            {
                test = node.InnerText();
            }
```

Html:

```
<div class="test">
        <ul>
            <li><b>Test1</b>Test1 Text</li>
            <li><b>Test2</b>Test2 Text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I need to extract "Test2 Text" without specific the ul tag in the xPath.

Comment: Showing some source html as well as describing your desired result will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using this XPath :

```
(//div[@class='test']//text()[normalize-space()])[last()]
```

`//div[@class='test']//text()[normalize-space()]` finds all *non-empty text nodes* within the `div`. And then, `[last()]` return only the last node from all found text nodes.

**Working demo example** (see it online [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qChEm7)) **:**

```
var html = @"<div class='test'>
<ul>
    <li><b>Test1</b>Test1 Text</li>
    <li><b>Test2</b>Test2 Text</li>
</ul>
";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("(//div[@class='test']//text()[normalize-space()])[last()]");
Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```

**output :**

```
Test2 Text
```